# Create table as select statement using procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

first of all i have 3 schema as follow ( MEDICINE, MEDICINE1 ,MEDICINE2) .
**MEDICINE** and **MEDICINE1** have same tables, **MEDICINE** have updated data and **MEDICINE1** have old data. and i have **MEDICINE2** with no tables so i want to create table in **MEDICINE2** as select from **MEDICINE** where not in **MEDICINE1**.

Ex. `create MEDICINE2.table1 as ( select * from MEDICINE.table1 minus select * MEDICINE1.table1 )`
so if table1 in schema MEDICINE has data (1,2,3,4,5,6) and MEDICINE1 has (1,2,3,4) so table1 will create in MEDICINE2 with data (5,6)

because i have many tables, i create this procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.create_table_from_schema IS
 TYPE own_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40)
    INDEX BY binary_integer;
 TYPE tab_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40)
    INDEX BY binary_integer;
  v_dml_str VARCHAR2 (400);
  v_own_array    own_array;
  v_tab_array    tab_array;
BEGIN

  SELECT owner,table_name,BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_own_array,v_tab_array
    from SYS.all_tables  
  where global_stats='YES'
  And owner = 'MEDICINE';


  FOR i IN v_tab_array.first..v_tab_array.last LOOP
    v_dml_str := 'Create table MEDICINE2.'
                 ||v_tab_array(i)||'as (select * from '||v_own_array(i)||'.'|| v_tab_array(i)
                 ||' minus select * from MEDICINE1.'|| v_tab_array(i)||' )'  ;             
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

but there is error will show

> PROCEDURE SYSTEM.CREATE_TABLE_FROM_SCHEMA On line:  11 PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00904: "BULK": invalid identifier

**Are there errors in procedure  ?**

thanks and regard,

Comment: remove comma `,` before `BULK COLLECT` in your SELECT statemtnt

Comment: Thanks @Hawk  , i didnt see it . now its work

Comment: @hawk now when i try to execute will show error, ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CREATE_TABLE_FROM_SCHEMA", line 22
ORA-06512: at line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working fine

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Declare
  v_dml_str VARCHAR2 (400);
  cursor c1 is
     SELECT owner,table_name
     from SYS.all_tables  
     where global_stats='YES'
     and owner = 'MEDICINE';
BEGIN

   FOR i in c1
   LOOP
    v_dml_str := 'Create table MEDICINE2.'
                 ||i.table_name||' as (select * from '||i.owner||'.'|| i.table_name
                 ||' minus select * from MEDICINE1.'|| i.table_name||' )'  ;             
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str;
            END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: @Md.ShamimAlMamun i don't know , as i told you it's give me error, but now when i take last solution u make i found the error in it and solve it , so now it's working, thank you , you help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It will execute without any errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.create_table_from_schema IS
  v_dml_str VARCHAR2 (400);
  v_own_array     VARCHAR2(128);
  v_tab_array   VARCHAR2(128);
  cursor c1 is
     SELECT owner,table_name
    from SYS.all_tables  
  where global_stats='YES'
  And owner = 'MEDICINE';
BEGIN

   FOR i in c1
   LOOP
    v_dml_str := 'Create table MEDICINE2.'
                 ||i.table_name||' as (select * from '||i.owner||'.'|| i.table_name
                 ||' minus select * from MEDICINE1.'|| i.table_name||' )'  ;             
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks but it's give an error. 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 15

Comment: now it's working after i delete  ( EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str;) , and it's execute without any errors. but table not created

Comment: Without this statement EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str; table cannot be created. But I did not get any error. Please share the error.

Comment: This is error with (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE )

 ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CREATE_TABLE_FROM_SCHEMA", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: I did not get any error. Forget the previous solution and find another answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you can use. Go to the SQL prompt as system user. execute this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Declare
  v_dml_str VARCHAR2 (400);
  cursor c1 is
     SELECT owner,table_name
     from SYS.all_tables  
     where global_stats='YES'
     and owner = 'MEDICINE';
BEGIN

   FOR i in c1
   LOOP
    v_dml_str := 'Create table MEDICINE2.'
                 ||i.table_name||' as (select * from '||i.owner||'.'|| i.table_name
                 ||' minus select * from MEDICINE1.'|| i.table_name||' );'  ;             
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dml_str;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_dml_str);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Now copy and execute the scripts generated.

Comment: i use the previous one , and i remove semicolon from the (    ||' minus select * from MEDICINE1.'|| i.table_name||' );'  ;) and it's work fine now